# navbar with sticky glitches when submenu opens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a navbar with sticky using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. A submenu is opened when hovered over the nav-list elements. I have included the code for all below. The problem I am facing is, that if sticky is active and I open my submenu, it causes a glitch for a macro-second with the height of my navbar. Further, the frequency of the glitch is arbitrary. I  have attached an image of my glitch. What is causing this and how can I stop it?

[image: Image of distorted height navbar]

```js
function scrollDetect() {
  const navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
  let lastScroll = 0;

  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

    if (currentScroll > 0 && lastScroll <= currentScroll) {
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    } else {
      navbar.classList.add("sticky");
    }

    lastScroll = currentScroll;

    if (currentScroll < 100) {
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  });
}

scrollDetect();
```

```css
  .main-navbar {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 100%;
  top: 3.7rem;
  height: 4.5rem;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 5.3rem;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.nav-list a {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-list>li>a {
  font-size: 1.07rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 10px 15px 2rem 15px;
}

.nav-list>li>a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 3.9px;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 14px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: 1.1rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}

.nav-list>li:hover .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.sub-menu a {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 3rem 40px 0 40px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.sub-menu a:hover {
  color: #7e7978;
}

.nav-list>li:hover>a::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  animation: faceInEffect 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation: faceInEffect 0.3s;
  border-bottom: none;
}

@keyframes faceInEffect {
  from {
    top: -5rem;
  }
  to {
    top: 0rem;
  }
}

.logo a svg {
  margin-left: 12%;
  width: 300px;
  transition: width 0.2s ease;
}

.logo a svg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.rightnav {
  position: relative;
  right: 2.9%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 100rem;
```

```html
<div class="main-navbar" id="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="">
      <svg>
            
          </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="">NEW</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" data-menu="submenu1">
          <a href="">Men</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu" id="submenu1">
            <li><a href="">shirts</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Shorts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" data-menu="submenu2">
          <a href="">Women</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu" id="submenu2">
            <li><a href="#">shirts</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Shorts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="rightnav">
    <div class="search-bar">
      <form>
        <div class="clickclass">
          <input class=" search bt-outline" type="text" placeholder="Search">
          <button class="bt-outline" id="clear-button">Clear</button>
          <a class="search-button" type="submit">
          </a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="content">
  hello
</div>
```

Comment: in the code snip, i only see a weirdly aligned html-only navbar without any styles or any other content, and the navbar also isn't sticky

Comment: Hey @danik0011,  the navbar looks weird due to the presence of other divs and other styling in my source code. I didn't include the divs and styling in the above snippet to make the code conscience but retained most of the styling. The sticky is working. Scroll to the end of the page or scroll up in between.

Comment: Please elaborate on the difference between the current result and the intended result. I can't discern what the actual issue is.

Comment: it's a simple code. When hovered on the nav-list a submenu becomes visible. I have no problem with this aspect of the code. The problem is, when the sticky is active (when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page or when they scroll up) and I open the submenu, at random  frequency, the height of the navbar glitches(it becomes large) for a macro-second before the submenu opens.

Comment: Why are you not using `position: sticky` to implement this?

Comment: hey @BrettDonald, I am not using the sticky position because- due to the nature of my sticky, when it is activated, the navbar is removed from the web flow causing all the other elements to shift up, creating a snap effect which I don't want. I can solve this by creating a pseudo element in the place of my navbar but it just complicates the code

Comment: Your snippet does not reproduce the problem. I would like to help you, but a prerequisite for that is that I can reproduce your problem using your snippet. That would be my starting point, finding out what is the actual cause, fixing it and explaining it. But the lack of a reproducible example prevents me from doing that and I will not invest time into trying and creating an example where the problem reproduces, because it is quite possible that something is missing from the question or I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: hey @LajosArpad, I get what you are saying. Even I can't identify the problem. The problem becomes trickier because the glitch happens at random times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this rule in your CSS, so that your submenus are under hovered nav-item.

```
.nav-item {
   position: relative;
}
```

After this I tried your code and the issue is not happening.